# Ansible playbook gets stuck trying to perform mysql operations

Tags: mysql, ansible

I'm trying to perfrom a simple "SHOW DATABASES;" command with an ansible playbook and it gets stuck when executes the command.

I tried different options

```
- hosts: servers
  become: true
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "db_passw"
      prompt: "DB root password?"
  tasks:
    - name: Configure Database
      shell: |
        mysql -u root -p {{ db_passw }} < ~/sql_query.sql
```

Also

```
- hosts: servers
  become: true
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "db_passw"
      prompt: "DB root password?"
  tasks:
    - name: Configure Database
      shell: |
        mysql -u root -p {{ db_passw }} -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
```

And I also tried, just as a test, to put the password explicitly

```
- hosts: servers
  become: true
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "db_passw"
      prompt: "DB root password?"
  tasks:
    - name: Configure Database
      shell: |
        mysql -u root -p <root_passw> -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
```

But it always gets stuck at the same point. I tried to execute above's mysql commands in the remote machine shell and they work with no problems. I also tried to execute other commands before mysql's ones and they are being executed.

Is there any problem between ansible and mysql?

I know thta there is a MySQL module for Ansible, but it's functionality is too limited.

Thank you

Comment: You need to surround what you pass to the shell in quotes for ansible to put the value of the variable into it, so `shell: "mysql -u root -p {{ db_passw }} -e \"SHOW DATABASES;\" "`

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. The play below

```
- hosts: dbserver
  tasks:
    - command: |
        mysql -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result
```

gives:

```
TASK [debug] 
ok: [dbserver] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": [
            "mysql", 
            "-e", 
            "SHOW DATABASES;"
        ], 
        "delta": "0:00:00.010958", 
        "end": "2019-04-04 16:19:58.359100", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2019-04-04 16:19:58.348142", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": 
        ...
```

It's not necessary to specify "-u root" when "become: true". I haven't set a MySQL password for root.

Comment: Still not working.

`- hosts: servers
  become: true
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "db_passw"
      prompt: "DB root password?"
  tasks:
    - command: 'mysql -p {{ db_passw }} -e "SHOW DATABASES;"'
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result`

Comment: Yes. There is no problem with quotation. Make sure the command works from the command line.